# How to test a window.confirm method inside of a React component using enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, confirm

I have a block button that uses `window.confirm` to check if someone really wants to block something. In my test, after `aButton.simulate('click');` I want to check if the confirmation was canceled. I tried wrapping the check in an if block:

```
  if (window.confirm == 'false') {
    expect(api.postRequest.calledOnce).to.equal(false);
  }
```

but enzyme doesn't like that. Is there a way I can check if a `window.confirm` has been canceled in my tests?

**block_button_spec.js**

```
it('DOES NOT call postRequest when Block is clicked, it is NOT disabled, and confirm is canceled', () => {
  wrapper.setState({ disabled: false });
  const aButton = wrapper.find('button');
  aButton.simulate('click');
  // code to check window.confirm was canceled
  expect(api.postRequest.calledOnce).to.equal(false);
});
```

**block_button.js**

```
  handleClick = () => {
    if (window.confirm(this.confirmBlockAll())) {
      this.disableButton();
      const promise = postRequest(this.props.blockPath);
      promise.then((err) => {
        const snackbarMessage = JSON.parse(err.response.text);
        this.openSnackbar(snackbarMessage);
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Where and how do you cancel the confirmation?

Comment: @OrB in the browser of course: ![img](https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/271T2t2E1r3h2L1a0j1S/Screen%20Shot%202018-01-24%20at%2012.56.13.png)